# How to save the selected theme when I switch pages or reload( html/css/js)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, toggle

I have not used toggle function in my code.
I have just switched the stylesheet when the click happens. But if I switch between pages or refresh the page it just go back to its default stylesheet.

It restores back to it's default "Off" mode when I refresh the Page.

How can I save it's position on Page Refresh and Switching the HTML page? Kindly share the code as well.

Thanks

Comment: turning off ETags and setting no-cache in HTTP header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is resolved. Here I have not changed the particular class or property ,directly changed the stylesheet.

```
const theme = document.querySelector("#theme-link");  //ID to be added in stylesheet link
const btn = document.querySelector("#checkbox"); 
const btnValue = localStorage.getItem("themeBtn");
if (btnValue === null || btnValue === "null") {
    localStorage.setItem("themeBtn", btn.checked);
    applyTheme(localStorage.getItem("themeBtn"));}
if (btnValue === "true" || btnValue === "false") {
    applyTheme(btnValue);}
btn.addEventListener("change", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("themeBtn", btn.checked);
    applyTheme(localStorage.getItem("themeBtn"));
});

function applyTheme(value) {
    if (value === "true") {
        theme.href = "/css/light-theme.css";
        btn.checked = true;
    } else if (value === "false") {
        theme.href = "/css/style.css";
        btn.checked = false;
    }
 }
```